# Ajax request are failing for asp.net mvc app using AzureAD OIDC protocal when session cookie expires

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, asp.net-ajax, openid-connect

I have a asp.net mvc 5 app which uses OpenID Connect (OIDC) protocol to provide authentication on Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). When a user starts a new session using the MVC Web App a new cookie is returned to control this session. This "session cookie" is created based on "ID Token" and as long as this cookie is valid, user will be considered as authenticated in MVC Web App. Here by default, the "id_token" will last one hour, and this duration will be the same for the "session cookie"

I followed the following links for implementation

https://jamuro-blog.azurewebsites.net/post/managing-azure-ad-sessions-and-ajax-calls-in-aspnet-mvc-apps-with-open-id-connect-authentication
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/

Here goes my code :

**Startup.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
  public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always                
            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = new Func<AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification, Task>(this.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived),
                    AuthenticationFailed = new Func<AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>, Task>(this.OnAuthenticationFailed),
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context) => {
                        string appBaseUrl = string.Concat(new object[] { context.Request.Scheme, "://", context.Request.Host, context.Request.PathBase });
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = tenant;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },
                UseTokenLifetime = true
            });
        }
}
```

Here as per my analysis SlidingExpiration value is true

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
  CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always                
});
```

I have also implemented the logic to renew the session by using iFrame mentioned in the article.

The only difference between the article and my implementation is I have not explicitly set SlidingExpiration = false

Here are my testing scenarios in case "session cookie" expired

1. If the next call to the MVC Web app is made without using AJAX, the ADAL MW included in the backend will detect this issue and try to renew automatically the cookie. When performing this action, you can see that the Web app connects to Azure and then, returns to the initial application calling page more or less in a proper way.
2. If the next call to the MVC Web App is made by using AJAX, then I see an issue.

In summary, I would like to say if the session cookie is expired and then I perform any action without using AJAX it works, but if I perform any action then involves AJAX usage then it breaks.

Here goes the timings that I used for testing scenario:

10:00 AM -> I logged into the application and landed into the Screen_1

10:00 AM – 10:20 AM -> I remained in Screen_1

10:20 AM -> I navigated to Screen_2

10:20 AM – 10:40 AM -> I remained in Screen_2

10:40 AM -> I navigated to Screen_3

10:40 AM – 11:05 -> I remained in Screen_3

11:06 AM -> I clicked a button which involves AJAX action and I see the error.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: I am using session variables to manage data in the application. I logged into the application successfully. After 20-30 min when I perform any AJAX action I see error: object reference not set to an instance of an object when data is retrieved from the session variables. Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue ?

Comment: If I do the same AJAX action within 20 min I see it works for me. Can any help me to know is there any dependency on session timeout here in this case?

Comment: Why don't you have browser JS get its own id_token using Implicit Grant and keep it or renew it from the browser (MSAL.JS may help)? Apart from solving your cookie issue it will also reduce chances of CSRF attacks.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue related to session timeout by extending the sessionstate timeout=60 and increasing the idle timeout property of the application pool associated with the application.